# Why do we use analytic coordinates to characterize singularity?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I read about Du Val singularities on surface are classified by equations of ADE type. For example, $x^2+y^2+z^{n+1}=0$ for A type. As not every surface can have a neighbourhood embedded in $\mathbb{A}^3$. Why do we use analytic coordinates to characterize singularity?

Comment: The same issue comes up when describing families of semistable curves (say with smooth generic fiber):  one can always get by using the etale topology (appropriately formulated) without recourse to analytic methods, ultimately due to the Artin approximation theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that, *locally*, any Du Val singularity (that is, any isolated surface singularity that arises by contracting an $A$-$D$-$E$ curve) can be realized as a double cover of a nonsingular surface. This means that there exist local analytic coordinates such that the germ of singularity has the form $$x^2=f(y, \, z),$$
that is the corresponding embedding dimension is $3$. In other words, even if the surface is not globally embeddable in $\mathbb{A}^3$, an analytic neighbourhood of the singularity always is.

A good reference is [Barth-Peters-Van De Ven, *Compact Complex Surfaces*, Springer 1984], see in particular Lemma 3.8 of Chapter III.

Comment: dear Francesco: could one use étale or formal coordinates instead?

Comment: For formal coordinates the answer is *yes*. This follows from Corollary 1.6 of M. Artin's paper *On the solutions of analytic equations*..

Comment: @user125763: It also follows from Artin approximation (the earlier paper of Artin...) that if $(X,x)$ and $(X',x')$ are pointed schemes of finite type over a field or excellent Dedekind domain $R$ and $f:\mathscr{O}_{X,x}^{\wedge} \simeq \mathscr{O}_{X',x'}^{\wedge}$ is an $R$-isomorphism then there is a common residually trivial pointed etale neighborhood $(X'',x'')$ of $(X,x)$ and $(X',x')$ which induces an isomorphism between those completed local rings that agrees with $f$ modulo whatever power of the maximal ideals you like. Same for arbitrary excellent schemes via Popescu's approx. thm.

Comment: @user76758: thanks! can I ask what residually trivial mean?

Comment: @user125763: trivial residue field extension at the marked points (so ensures induced map on completions from the etale morphism is an *isomorphism*).